# Creating a custom TextFieldView produces weird animation

Tags: swiftui

I want to create a custom TextFieldView so that I can be able to reuse it throughout my app. The problem I am facing has to do with the animation. I have an HStack that contains a TF and an Image. I want to show the image if the focus field equals the assigned field and the text is not empty. The thing is everything works but when I submit and refocus the field the image animation is weird.

This how my custom TF looks like

```
enum Field {
    case email, name
}

struct TV3TFV: View {
    let placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    var ff: FocusState<Field?>.Binding
    var assignedField: Field
    @State var isShowingDeleteSign: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                .focused(ff, equals: assignedField)
            
            if isShowingDeleteSign { // Remove this and always show image but change opacity based on isShowingDeleteSign works
                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                //                    .opacity(isShowingDeleteSign ? 1 : 0) // Add this and keep the image always showing works
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(height: 44)
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous))
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
            //            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.1)) { // Change this
            isShowingDeleteSign = !text.isEmpty
            //            }
            
        }
        .onChange(of: ff.wrappedValue) { newValue in
            //            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.1)) { // Change this
            isShowingDeleteSign = ff.wrappedValue == assignedField && !text.isEmpty
            //            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I add the with animation for the isShowingDeleteSign the text inside the textfield bounces. This is how I would use it.

```
struct TV3: View {
    @FocusState var ff: Field?
    @State var email = ""
    @State var username = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            TV3TFV(placeholder: "email", text: $email, ff: $ff, assignedField: .email)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use opacity?

Comment: I tested your code with Xcode 14 and iOS 16. Every animation worked fine. There was no bounce at all. All animations were opacity.

Comment: @Asperi I wanted to know why this happens when I use the if statement.

Comment: @tail yeah it works with opacity but not with the if statement

Comment: @Luis both If and Opacity worked in my previous test.

Comment: @tail I would need to download Xcode 14 and check it out cause its does a weird animation on Xcode 13.4.1